# How to Manage 2 Elasticsearch's Client only node?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, load-balancing, horizontal-scaling

We are using elasticsearch for only searching purpose, our topology is

3 Master+Data nodes and 2 Client only nodes (Load Balancer)

say now 
my 1st client node has IP `x.x.x.x`
and my 2nd client node has IP `y.y.y.y`

In my PHP ESClient do i need to specify IP address of these 2 clients or i need to specify only one clients IP address and ES will automatically handle the scenario where if one client node goes down the other will take over it (and we wont have any downtime).

Currently I am specifying only one IP like

```
$esconfig = [
    'hosts' =   [ SEARCHIP . ":" . SEARCHPORT ],
    'logging' = false,
    'logPath' = LOGFILE,
    'logPermission' =   0664   ];

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($esconfig);
```

Please we need your help

Comment: _"ES community help us"_ We aren't ES community, we are the SO community!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$esconfig = [ 'hosts' => [ SEARCHIP_1 . ":" . 9200,  SEARCHIP_2 . ":" . 9200], 'logging' => false, 'logPath' => LOGFILE, 'logPermission' => 0664 ];

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($esconfig);
```